# Language.properties file in Liferay

Tags: java, internationalization, liferay

I want to support multiple languages for my portlet application. So I:

1. Created `content` package in `src` folder.
2. Created `Language.properties` file with string `Book-Name=Book Name`
3. Paste this line

   ```
    <supported-locale>es</supported-locale> 
    <resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>
   ```

   in `portlet.xml` file.

---

So could you please tell me why I still have `Book-Name` here?!

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
<liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${bookListArray}" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="com.softwerke.model.Book" modelVar="aBook">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName" name="Book-Name"/>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookDescription" name="Description"/>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/html/action.jsp" align="right" />
     </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
     <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

> UPDATE

This:

```
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName" name="${bookName}" />
```

....

```
   <c:set var="bookName"> <liferay-ui:message key="book-Name" /> </c:set>
```

does ***NOT*** work too

Comment: Did you try using `LanguageUtil.get(pageContext, "Book-Name")`? Liferay UI taglib `liferay-ui:message` does the same.

Comment: Look at `\util-taglib\src\com\liferay\taglib\ui\MessageTag.java` in portal source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using it at all. 
The `name="Book-Name"` in this line

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName" name="Book-Name"/>
```

adds name property to this html component with valye defined inside the quotation marks to make this value the one defined in the properties file you have to use  `<liferay-ui:message /> tag` in your case it would be:
:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName" name="<liferay-ui:message key="Book-Name" />"/>
```

Also it is not relevant but a dev  practice that the language key is all lower case.

Comment: No, it seems to work but it doesn't. I tryed `liferay-ui` and `fmt`.

Comment: May be I should change smth in Build Path?

Comment: Are you sure your language file is being loaded?!

Comment: No, I described ALL my steps above. May be I missed something but I don't know why. Help me please :)

Comment: @German I just realised your file name doesn't match to the one defined in portlet.xml

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault, it's all ok with it.

Comment: @German try changing `resource-bundle>content/Language</resource-bundle>` to `resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>`  and create `src/main/resources` as a source folder with the content folder in it