# Scriplets in Liferay

Tags: liferay, scriptlet

What can I do with this scriptlet

```
<%
    ResultRow row = (ResultRow) request.getAttribute(BookAndAuthor.SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW);

    Book book = (Book) row.getObject();
%>
```

If I want to use `value="${book.BookId}` in this code?

```
<liferay-ui:icon-menu>

     <portlet:actionURL name="deleteBook" var="deleteBookVar">
         <portlet:param name="bookId"     value="<%=String.valueOf(book.getBookId())%>" />
     </portlet:actionURL>

</liferay-ui:icon-menu>
```

Comment: What is the problem, you are facing?

Comment: @ParkashKumar I can't use scriplets in my project at all, it's task rule. I know that I can use JSTL and EL somehow, but I don't know how. :(

Comment: You can first use JSTL to set these values using `c:set` then, use these with variable names using EL.

Comment: `<c:set var="row" value="${request.getAttribute(BookAndAuthor.SEARCH_CONTAINER_RESULT_ROW)}"/>` Something like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Could you please help me with another question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39366942/language-properties-file-in-liferay

Comment: And post your comment as answer, I'll vote up and check as helpful

Comment: NO, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: It worked or not? Your two comments are confusing. :p

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I know I should use c:set, but another way. :(

Comment: Did you try changing `${` with scriptlet `<%=`?

Comment: I inserted you code instead of my scriplet and then use ${row.BookId}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122838/discussion-between-german-and-parkash-kumar).

Comment: First set `<c:set var="row" value="${(ResultRow) request.getAttribute(BookAndAuthor.SEARCH_CONTAINER‌​_RESULT_ROW)}"/>` then `<c:set var="book" value="${(Book) row.getObject()}"/>` and then use it `${book.BookId}`

Comment: @ParkashKumar It still doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky but I thing it should work.
Use a variable to hold the value of the constant `SEARCH_CONTAINER‌​_RESULT‌​_ROW`

`<c:set var="resultRowConstant" value="<%=BookAndAuthor.SEARCH_CONTAINER‌​_RESULT‌​_ROW%>" />`
than to read the attribute you you should be able to use bracket notation to access 'dynamic' properties:
`<c:set var="row" value="${[resultRowConstant]}"/>` and that will hold the `ResultRow` object, than you access your book object through

```
${row.object}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. SEARCH_CONTAINER‌​_RESULT‌​_ROW is underlined and `Syntax error on tokens, delete  these tokens` message.

Comment: So? I don't understand, sorry

Comment: You have to import the BookAndAuthor class to use it, like you do in java classes

Comment: Of course I have already imported my class. So this problem is somewhere else.